# mysql query group by

Tags: mysql

the following query brings a record for each time a recipecomments.RecipeID appears , i would just like to bring one record for each recipeID , group by recipeid does not seem to work

```
SELECT recipecomments.RecipeID
      ,recipecomments.CommentID 
      ,recipes.RecipeID
      ,recipes.Name
      ,recipes.CategoryID
      ,recipes.RatingTotal
      ,recipes.ImageMed
FROM recipecomments 
     JOIN recipes ON recipecomments.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID                 
ORDER BY recipecomments.CommentID
```

Comment: if you only want one comment, do you want the most recent comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're grouping by recipeid, you need to decide which CommentID you want to show.
From your syntax, I'm guessing the highest.

```
 SELECT 
      recipecomments.RecipeID,
      MAX(recipecomments.CommentID),
      recipes.RecipeID,
      recipes.Name, 
      recipes.CategoryID,
      recipes.RatingTotal,
      recipes.ImageMed
 FROM recipecomments   
                JOIN recipes ON recipecomments.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
 group by 
      recipecomments.RecipeID,
      recipes.RecipeID,
      recipes.Name, 
      recipes.CategoryID,
      recipes.RatingTotal,
      recipes.ImageMed
```